# Don't create database in ubuntu through PHP query

Tags: php, database, ubuntu

```
<code>
require 'INewsDB.class.php';
class NewsDB implements INewsDB{
protected  $_db;
const DB_NAME = '/var/www/mysite/news.db';
/**
 *
 */
function __construct(){
    if(is_file(self::DB_NAME)){
    $this->_db = new SQLite3(self::DB_NAME);
    }else{
        $this->_db = new SQLite3(self::DB_NAME);
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE msgs(
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                title TEXT,
                category INTEGER,
                description TEXT,
                source TEXT,
                datetime INTEGER)";
        $this->_db->exec($sql) or die($this->_db->lastErrorMsg());
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE category(
                id INTEGER,
                name TEXT)";
        $this->_db->exec($sql) or die($this->_db->lastErrorMsg());
        $sql = "INSERT INTO category(id, name)
                SELECT 1 as id, 'Политика' as name
                UNION SELECT 2 as id, 'Культура' as name
                UNION SELECT 3 as id, 'Спорт' as name";
        $this->_db->exec($sql) or die($this->_db->lastErrorMsg());
    }
}
function __destruct(){
    unset($this->_db);
}
function saveNews($title, $category, $description, $sourse){}
function getNews(){}
function deleteNews($id){}
}
$news = new NewsDB;
interface INewsDB{ // other file(implement)
function saveNews($title, $category, $description, $source);
function getNews();
function deleteNews($id);
</code>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

folder path /var/www/mysite mysite - 755; user: Me ubuntu 14.10 desktop P.S
```

This problem was with MySQL too. But i am try again on SQLlite but i don't solve it.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact error that you receive? Look into your servers log plz.

Comment: are you mean log in the ubuntu or browser? because i have many folder in log but in browser i have 1 message error in console

Comment: In the server that serves PHP (e.g. apache). If it's on an Ubuntu machine, yes the "ubuntu log"

Comment: [Fri Mar 20 09:51:13.492080 2015] [:error] [pid 15318] [client 127.0.0.1:39082] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SQLite3' not found in /var/www/mysite/news/NewsDB.class.php on line 14, referer: http://mysite.loc/news/   -- it's error repeating several times

Comment: I installed sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite and i got another error [Fri Mar 20 11:27:50.360356 2015] [:error] [pid 8534] [client 127.0.0.1:40123] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file' in /var/www/mysite/news/NewsDB.class.php:14\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/mysite/news/NewsDB.class.php(14): SQLite3->__construct('/var/www/mysite...')\n#1 /var/www/mysite/news/NewsDB.class.php(41): NewsDB->__construct()\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/mysite/news/NewsDB.class.php on line 14, referer: http://mysite.loc/news/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a permissions problem.

Make sure your DB file has read/write permissions set, your folder `/mysite` may have `0x755` permissions, **but** your files **inside of it** most probably have only `0x644`, which is the default configuration for Linux/Apache.

Comment: /www
drwxr-xr-x 9 petrov petrov 4096 Mar 20 10:02 mysite
/mysite
drwxr-xr-x 2 petrov petrov 4096 Mar 20 10:03 news
/news
-rwxr-xr-x 1 petrov petrov 1106 Mar 18 08:37 INewsDB.class.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 petrov petrov 1431 Mar 20 10:03 NewsDB.class.php

Answer (score 0):

Is the user with whome you are connecting to the db privileged to create tables?

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution my self

I try again - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

vary helpful

```
sudo find /home/user/public_html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /home/user/public_html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo chown user:group -R /home/user/public_html/
```

and

```
INSERT INTO category(id, name)
                SELECT 1 as id, 'Политика' as name
                UNION SELECT 2 as id, 'Культура' as name
```

UNION SELECT 3 as id, 'Спорт' as name**;**"; //  in all this query and my problem went away